# Find Last cell contains specific value and add a row below or if not found add new in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i hope to find help here, please i have a worksheet full of data (invoices)
there are invoices repeated in several rows, what i want is via userform when i type invoice number it finds the last row for the same invoice and add a new row below it to be able to deduct the new paid amount of this invoice, and if this invoice is new then it add it at the end of the sheet no problem. i hope below link is a sample indicates the repeated invoices number (highlighted) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2youyhl6pw2srsz/Book2.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: While you have been around for a while, I would still like to remind you that StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) with their code. Read the help again on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. I'd recommend a `Range.Find`, `xlByRows`, `xlPrevious` to get the latest occurrence of that number. `Range.Insert` with `xlShiftDown` will get you a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Macro1()

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("H1")
```

Call LR2

End Sub

Sub LR2()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lastrow, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub